# Swift SpriteKit Physics body with alpha channel not covering whole image

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have an image that has a couple of parts separated by transparency. I want to apply a physics body to it using an alpha mask. When I apply an alpha mask, only part of the image is surrounded by the mask.

[image]

As you can see, the Segment of this that is above this text right here is the only part of the image surrounded by the alpha mask(in blue).

How can I get it so the alpha mask will surround the whole entire image without creating separate images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to make an alpha mask cover the whole object. Instead I just broke the image into parts and they each had their own physics body. This worked well enough.